# java and jsp_session expired_redirect

Tags: java, javascript, xml, eclipse, jsp-tags

I am working with java and jsp for mail project. I want to redirect the page with xml r by some way when the session is expired or I want to deactivate the window when session is expired.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correct you want the Webbrowser to change to another page, if the session expires.

There are some ways to do this:

1. Javascript redirect with `setTimeout(location.href='/logoff.jsp', 3600)`
2. MATA-Tag REFESH: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3600; url=/loggedoff.jsp">`

In both examples, the session invalidates after 3600 seconds. You should redirect the browser slightly before the session invalidates, just to be sure.